# Galera cluster nodes do not trigger wsrep_notify_cmd and wsrep_sst_method

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, synchronized, galera

I did setup the `Galera cluster` with 3 nodes using 3 `docker containers`. There is a requirement that when data is synchronized from the `donor` node to the other nodes, based on the `wsrep_notify_cmd` trigger or `wsrep_sst_method` trigger at the synchronized node the data also need to be populated to the corresponding Redis queue at that node.
The problem is these 2 triggers are only invoked when I start the cluster.  There is log saying that these 2 triggers were invoked when one node has been joined the cluster. But when I tried to modify the schema or do CUD action in one node the triggers were not fired at the other nodes.
I dont know if I did the configuration incorrectly or it is not the way these triggers working.

Below is the files I use to make the cluster working

- docker-compose.yml

  ```
  version: '3'
  services:
    node1:
        build: ./galera/
        image: galera_mariadb:latest
        container_name: "galera_cluster_node1"
        hostname: node1
        ports:
          - 13306:3306
        networks:
          - galera_cluster
        volumes:
          - ./galera/conf.d/galera.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf
          - /var/data/galera/mysql/node1:/var/lib/mysql/
          # ./galera/scripts contains the bash script which is executed by wsrep_notify_cmd trigger
          - ./galera/scripts/:/etc/mysql/scripts/
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
          - REPLICATION_PASSWORD=123
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
          - MYSQL_USER=maria
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123
          - GALERA=On
          - NODE_NAME=node1
          - CLUSTER_NAME=maria_cluster
          - CLUSTER_ADDRESS=gcomm://
        command: --wsrep-new-cluster

    node2:
        image: galera_mariadb:latest
        container_name: "galera_cluster_node2"
        hostname: node2
        links:
          - node1
        ports:
          - 23306:3306
        networks:
          - galera_cluster
        volumes:
          - ./galera/conf.d/galera.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf
          - /var/data/galera/mysql/node2:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./galera/scripts/:/etc/mysql/scripts/
        environment:
          - REPLICATION_PASSWORD=123
          - GALERA=On
          - NODE_NAME=node2
          - CLUSTER_NAME=maria_cluster
          - CLUSTER_ADDRESS=gcomm://node1

    node3:
        image: galera_mariadb:latest
        container_name: "galera_cluster_node3"
        hostname: node3
        links:
          - node1
        ports:
          - 33306:3306
        networks:
          - galera_cluster
        volumes:
          - ./galera/conf.d/galera.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf
          - /var/data/galera/mysql/node3:/var/lib/mysql/
          - ./galera/scripts/:/etc/mysql/scripts/
        environment:
          - REPLICATION_PASSWORD=123
          - GALERA=On
          - NODE_NAME=node3
          - CLUSTER_NAME=maria_cluster
          - CLUSTER_ADDRESS=gcomm://node1

  networks:
    galera_cluster:
        driver: bridge
  ```
- The Dockerfile used to build 3 galera cluster nodes

  ```
  # Galera Cluster Dockerfile
  FROM hauptmedia/mariadb:10.1
  RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get -y install \
          vim \
          python \
          redis-tools

  # remove the default galera.cnf in the original image
  RUN rm -rf /etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf
  # add the custom galera.cnf
  COPY ./conf.d/galera.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf
  # grant access and execution right
  RUN chmod 755 /etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf
  ```
- galera.cnf file

  ```
  [galera]
  wsrep_on=ON

  # wsrep only supports binlog_format='ROW' and storage-engine=innodb
  binlog_format=row
  default_storage_engine=InnoDB

  # to avoid issues with 'bulk mode inserts' using autoinc
  innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2

  bind-address=0.0.0.0

  # relax flushing logs when running in galera mode
  innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
  sync_binlog=0

  # Query Cache is supported since version 10.0.14 with wsrep
  query_cache_size=8000000
  query_cache_type=1

  wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
  # use the built-in method to manage State Snapshot Transfers
  # we can customize this script to perform a specific logic
  wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
  # This bash is volumed from the host which is used to populate synchronized data to the Redis queue
  wsrep_notify_cmd=/etc/mysql/scripts/wsrep_notify.sh

  # force transaction level to be read commited
  #transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
  ```
- wsrep_notify.sh

  ```
  #!/bin/sh -eu

  wsrep_log()
  {
      # echo everything to stderr so that it gets into common error log
      # deliberately made to look different from the rest of the log
      local readonly tst="$(date +%Y%m%d\ %H:%M:%S.%N | cut -b -21)"
      echo "WSREP_SST: $* ($tst)" >&2
  }

  wsrep_log_info()
  {
      wsrep_log "[INFO] $*"
  }

  STATUS=""
  CLUSTER_UUID=""
  PRIMARY=""
  MEMBERS=""
  INDEX=""

  while [ $# -gt 0 ]
  do
     case $1 in
        --status)
           STATUS=$2
           shift
           ;;
        --uuid)
           CLUSTER_UUID=$2
           shift
           ;;
        --primary)
           PRIMARY=$2
           shift
           ;;
        --index)
           INDEX=$2
           shift
           ;;
        --members)
           MEMBERS=$2
           shift
           ;;
           esac
           shift
     done

  wsrep_log_info "--status $STATUS --uuid $CLUSTER_UUID --primary $PRIMARY --members $MEMBERS --index $INDEX"
  ```
- Here is the log files of 3 nodes

node1:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2q2F62RQxVjbkRaQlFrV2NyYnc/view?usp=sharing

node2:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2q2F62RQxVjX3hYZHBpQ2FRV0U/view?usp=sharing

node3:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2q2F62RQxVjelZHQTN3ZDRNZ0k/view?usp=sharing

I have been googling about this issue but there was no luck. I hope anyone who has experienced of Galera Cluster setup can help me to resolve the issue. Or there is another approach to solve the requirement please show me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

> wsrep_notify_cmd
>
> Defines the command the node runs whenever cluster membership or the
>   state of the node changes.

So, script will be started on node if it changes its status described in the list below to any other status:

> The possible statuses are:
>
> *Undefined* The node has just started up and is not connected to any Primary Component.
>
> *Joiner* The node is connected to a primary component and now is receiving state snapshot.
>
> *Donor* The node is connected to primary component and now is sending state snapshot.
>
> *Joined* The node has a complete state and now is catching up with the cluster.
>
> *Synced* The node has synchronized itself with the cluster.
>
> *Error*( if available>) The node is in an error state.

You see script notifies when nodes starts and changes their statuses. It will not notify when data just synchronizes between galera cluster nodes.

Comment: In this case which status variable we should use to check if data is synchronized at one node? I am wondering if I use https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/galera-cluster-status-variables/#wsrep_local_commits is the correct one.

Comment: I also think about triggers that I will create Insert/Update/Delete triggers for those tables where the data will be populated to the Redis. Is this a good approach and is there any performance issue needs to be noticed?